# How to find out what handlers are registered in express for a method/url pair?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How do I find out what handlers (and in what order) are registered in express for a method/url pair?

Comment: what version of express are you using?

Comment: I use Express 4 (^4.14.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array of "layer" handlers per a route can be read from:

```
req.route.stack // within a handler of the given route
```